# AJAX Request w/ a JSON response that updates URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code that does its job on page load, but I need to convert it to continuously send the request every 5 seconds on page load.  Each page load, the URL to the request will be updated with the JSON response variable data.update_hash replacing the current verification_code.  Would prefer to stick with $.getJSON as I plan to expand in the future.

The current:

```
$('#update_status').replaceWith($('<p id="update_status">'+data.update_hash+'</p>'));
```

Is only there for debug and to verify the request went through okay.  Normally nothing would be updated, just the URL for the next JSON request.

Background information:

- Using Fat Free Framework
- JQuery 1.10.1

  ```
      <check if="{{ @ajax_update }}"><script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $.getJSON( '/ajax/update-status/{{ @verification_code }}', {
        format: 'json'
      })
      .done(function( data ) {
          if ( data.status == 'continue' ) {
              $('#update_status').replaceWith($('<p id="update_status">'+data.update_hash+'</p>'));
          }
          else
          {
              $('#update_status').replaceWith($('<p id="update_status">'+data.message+'</p>'));
          }
      });
  });
  //]]>
  </script></check>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set up a recursive call within your `.done` handler, as so:

```
function getToken(url) {
    $.getJSON( url, {
        format: 'json'
    })
    .done(function( data ) {
        if ( data.status == 'continue' ) {
            $('#update_status').replaceWith($('<p id="update_status">'+data.update_hash+'</p>'));

            //calculate the new URL and call the function recursively after 5 seconds
            var newURL = '/ajax/update-status/' + data.update_hash;
            setTimeout(function (){
                getToken(newURL);
            }, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
            $('#update_status').replaceWith($('<p id="update_status">'+data.message+'</p>'));
        }
    });
}
```

You would then hook it up to the page load like so

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    getToken('/ajax/update-status/{{ @verification_code }}');
}
```